# Distribution over quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to learn concept of quantifiers in discrete mathematics. However, I am facing some issues in same. Please excuse me if  this is very basic as I am quite new to it.

I am trying to check if

```
(∀X∀Y (¬p(X,Y ) ∨ a(X,Y))) ∧ (∀X∀Y∀Z (¬ p(X,Y) ∨ ¬ a(Y,Z) ∨ a(X,Z)))
```

is logically equivalent to

```
(∀X∀Y∀Z (¬ p(X, Y )∨ a(X, Y )) ∧ (¬ p(X,Y) ∨ ¬ a(Y,Z) ∨ a(X,Z)))
```

or not?

Can someone please tell me on how can I prove this?

Comment: Do you know the distributive property for quantifiers?  If you know that it's fairly simple.  If not then this is basically asking you to verify the distributive property $\forall x (P(x) \land Q(x))=(\forall x P(x) \land \forall x Q(x)$